# Visual Studio 2022 duplicate shortcut has changed

Tags: visual-studio, duplicates, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

#### Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)

**Version 17.0.6**

I have been using <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> for years in **Visual Studio** however today **duplicate** no longer works. This has been working in vs 2022 for several months.

When I check the edit menu it shows <kbd>Ctrl+E,V</kbd>

[image]

I also noticed <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd> no longer work to move lines.

Any ideas how these shortcuts can be reset or what may have caused them to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by clicking reset mapping scheme.

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Environment
4. Keyboard
5. Reset

[image]

No idea how they got messed up in the first place because I have never touched these settings. Perhaps it was an extension.

My scheme still showed *(Default)* before clicking reset.

Comment: I can second this, maybe the new version has a new key mapping, but the Reset points to the settings from previous VS versions?

Comment: Have you checked if there were more than one defined ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 17.2.3 of Visual Studio Community. Going in and doing a reset didn't do anything for me. I found that Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V was the only thing that worked on a WinForm to duplicate either a single control or multiple controls.